# How to Execute Javascript inside html automatically and use ajax to send the variables into php?

Tags: javascript, php

I have found a java script that can measure user download speed and it is very close to the real speed and here is the code.

```
//JUST AN EXAMPLE, PLEASE USE YOUR OWN PICTURE!
var imageAddr = "http://www.kenrockwell.com/contax/images/g2/examples/31120037-5mb.jpg"; 
var downloadSize = 4995374; //bytes

function ShowProgressMessage(msg) {
    if (console) {
        if (typeof msg == "string") {
            console.log(msg);
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
                console.log(msg[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    var oProgress = document.getElementById("progress");
    if (oProgress) {
        var actualHTML = (typeof msg == "string") ? msg : msg.join("<br />");
        oProgress.innerHTML = actualHTML;
    }
}

function InitiateSpeedDetection() {
    ShowProgressMessage("Loading the image, please wait...");
    window.setTimeout(MeasureConnectionSpeed, 1);
};    

if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('load', InitiateSpeedDetection, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onload', InitiateSpeedDetection);
}

function MeasureConnectionSpeed() {
    var startTime, endTime;
    var download = new Image();
    download.onload = function () {
        endTime = (new Date()).getTime();
        showResults();
    }

    download.onerror = function (err, msg) {
        ShowProgressMessage("Invalid image, or error downloading");
    }

    startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    var cacheBuster = "?nnn=" + startTime;
    download.src = imageAddr + cacheBuster;

    function showResults() {
        var duration = (endTime - startTime) / 1000;
        var bitsLoaded = downloadSize * 8;
        var speedBps = (bitsLoaded / duration).toFixed(2);
        var speedKbps = (speedBps / 1024).toFixed(2);
        var speedMbps = (speedKbps / 1024).toFixed(2);
        ShowProgressMessage([
            "Your connection speed is:", 
            speedBps + " bps", 
            speedKbps + " kbps", 
            speedMbps + " Mbps"
        ]);
    }
}
```

I have really no experience with java script at all, First, I want to edit this code to execute without showing any messages at all and then I want it to run automatically in an empty html and using ajax to redirect page to a ( url + speedMbps javascript variable ).

For example, if the url is http://url.com/get.php?speed= and the speedMbps = 23 then I want the redirect url to look like that http://url.com/get.php?speed=23

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: the name of the language is JavaScript ;)

Comment: Haha. Told you my first time with it, I am trying to make script to measure user download speed and send it as a variable to php?